# Stream Processing Framework Vs Database

Tags: oracle, plsql, spark-streaming, apache-flink

Why it is not possible to do real time streaming processing using database sql using cursors, PL SQL , Triggers etc. Why do we need a separate stream processing framework like Spark.

Comment: For the same reason we drink water from a glass rather than a hosepipe.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible now. You can familiarize yourself with the concept of streaming databases, and there are mature products available in the market now. A streaming database combines the capabilities of a traditional database with the ability to handle high-speed, real-time data ingestion. They store and manage data while enabling real-time querying and retrieval. In essence, a streaming database is a database equipped to handle continuous streams of data alongside traditional query operations.

Several streaming databases have gained popularity in recent years, each with unique features and strengths:

RisingWave: RisingWave is an open-source distributed SQL database designed for stream processing. It processes streaming data using PostgreSQL-style SQL as the interface, allowing users to ingest, manage, query, and store continuously generated data streams. RisingWave reduces the complexity and cost of building real-time applications by consuming streaming data, performing incremental computations as new data arrives, and updating results dynamically.

KsqlDB: KsqlDB is an open-source streaming SQL engine for Apache Kafka, simplifying the development of real-time stream processing applications. It enables users to express stream processing logic through SQL-like queries, making it accessible to data analysts and developers proficient in SQL. KsqlDB can process and analyze data in real-time from Kafka topics, handling tasks like data transformation, filtering, and aggregation.

Materialize: Materialize is a streaming database that leverages SQL for processing. It can automatically refresh materialized views in a consistent manner, allowing concurrent querying of data in these views. Materialize builds upon Timely Dataflow, developed by Microsoft Research to support incremental and iterative processing. It employs a hot-standby model for fault tolerance.

Timeplus: Timeplus is a data analytics platform designed with a focus on streaming-first analytics, enabling organizations to process both streaming and historical data quickly and intuitively. It empowers data and platform engineers to unlock the value of streaming data using SQL

DeltaStream: DeltaStream is a stream processing platform designed for developing and deploying streaming applications. It is built on Apache Flink, offering a unified SQL interface for querying and processing streaming data using standard SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Stream processors can scale better and more consistently operate with low latency and high throughput.